# IIS PHP Remote IE Sessions reseting on page load

Tags: php, internet-explorer, iis, session-cookies

I've looked absolutely everywhere to a solution for this, but every solution hasn't worked.

**My problem**
I have a php site running on IIS, When I log in on IE explorer my sessions reset on every page load.

However it works on Chrome, Firefox, Safari AND IE on when browsing on the server.

**Things i've tried**

- Checked the server name, its all one word, so no underscores (as I saw this fixed it for some people).
- Set headers to allow third part cookies (Although I shouldn't have to as this is on an intranet). Anyways it didn't work.
- Permissions are not an issue, The cookie gets stored on c:\php\tmp - It also works in all other browsers.
- Internet explorer cookies and security are set to allow all.
- This happens in both compatibility and normal mode.

**Things to note**

- I've set php to log errors into the event viewer... There are no errors.
- Tried this in IE 11, haven't tried it in other version of IE.
- Domain layout is myservername:3000
- Its mapped in IIS to localhost port 3000 (could this be an issue? When browsing on the server I browse to it using localhost - and sessions work - but via an internal connection I use the server name eg: myservername:3000).

**Leading up to the error**

- I enter login details.
- Get redirected and the network shows a cookie with a PHPSESSID value which is the same as the session file stored on the server. Pic below:

[image]
After submit and redirect i have the session, but navigate after that and the session cookie is lost.

I literally have no other ideas on how to fix this. Help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Ok So after posting this and reading it through I've figured it out. Since it was such a pain the never regions I thought it best to share, Upon inspecting the cookie data in the IE DevTools > Network panel, I noticed the Cookie path and domain were incorrect.

So in my php.ini settings I commented out the session.domain and session.save_path variables (which were set to point to localhost and php\tmp respectively (as you can see in the IE DevTools picture).

Double checked that they were set to "not set" in phpinfo(); recycled the app pool, and BAM! Now IE is keeping session cookies across all pages in line with all other browsers.

Jay